# Bootstrap modal not working with same code in different pages

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code on 2 pages:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Sign Up" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>

      <!-- my modal dialog-->

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New User</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="myform" action="add_user.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password-input" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password-confirm-input" placeholder="Confirm Password" onblur=";"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="User Type"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="msg">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name=email placeholder="E-mail Address"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label id="label" for="male"></label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group pull-right">
                  <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="create_user2" value="Create User"/>
                </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This code works on the index.php page, a modal dialog pops up.
in another page, dashboard.php, it does not.

I have the exact same button and modal code in the body tags

Comment: do you have multiple modals in dashboard? this behavior may be caused to duplicated IDs

Comment: I do not so far, just this dialog :(

Comment: how do you move between pages? is it possible that some HTML from index remained in dashboard?

Comment: do you have all the JS dependencies in both pages?

Comment: I believe so, if this is what you're referring to:
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

which is exactly the same in the other page

Comment: you'll need bootstrap JS files as well

Comment: I move between pages as follows:
index > login    via POST
login > dashboard via redirection
I don;t know what you mean by html from index :(

Comment: I have the following on both pages:
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: you are using bootstrap modals, so you'll need bootstrap js files...

Comment: add this tag: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: (be careful with the link, it has been shorten)

Comment: <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DCF791F23E7F3B9C</RequestId>
<HostId>
m64gNqUvs0LYwcT2evOZ4YEcnq7/lbCN5Iz976xdSWA781k0mTpBbsX+l0CqfLle9msekYI5InY=
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: what's that suppoused to be?

Comment: crap crap crap
I've referenced them at the end of the firts file
You are right, I've referenced them in the second file and everything is working now :)

Comment: You can mark my post as answer for future people then  :)

Comment: done 
I appreciate your effort and time :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you have bootstrap JS references in both pages:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```